# staratlas "initiating withdrow cooldown"

Tags: solana-program, phantom

I would unstake my atlas , but when I start withdrow cooldown I receive the error "program Error:"Instruction #Failed" , I use latest version phantom wallet.
detail.
what hould I do?

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3sh9hk6UXeuj5Hn35ZfdW2dx1PdJwy2kkgAJjfvF8vn2mJ4GCSCZLe39CYYgySBpoASe6XW4yeF6PWcWATC6Torx?cluster=mainnet-beta

Comment: You may not get Star Atlas support here unfortunately. Please try any of their official support channels